# Windows Forms PictureBox Bitmap size issue

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, picturebox

I have an issue with different image sizes and the PictureBox from the Windows forms. The box is `640*480` pixels large. Displaying a vaiety of image sizes works fine, but some image sizes causes the program to crash with `Parameter is not valid` exception in the line where I assign the bitmap to the Picturebox:

```
System::Drawing::Bitmap ^pictureBimage = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(resEnhWidth, resEnhHeight, resEnhWidth * sizeof(char)* 3, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, (System::IntPtr) pictureBox24bitLargeImage);
this->pictureBox1->Image = pictureBimage;
this->pictureBox1->Show();
```

`650*600` works, `640*480` as well, but for example `550*630` causes the crash. Does anyone of you know why and how to fix this?

Cheers

**EDIT**:

This could possibly help solving the problem: The `pictureBox24bitLargeImage` is refreshed every time the image is displayed in the pictureBox:

```
                     unsigned char* temp = getByteImFromImageData(showThis2, (hScrollBar2->Value)*width*height, width*height, manContrast);
                 for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++){
                     memset(pictureBox24bitImage + 3 * i, *(temp + i), 3);
                 }
                 if (draw_Rectangle){
                     drawRectangle(pictureBox24bitImage, rect_upperLeftCorner, rect_lowerRightCorner, width, height);
                 }
                 free(temp);
```

The temp array contains values between 0 and 255. Is is created with the `getByteImFromImageData` function, which takes a double array and rescales the double values between 0 and 255. If a manual contrast is set then it stretches the doule values between user defined values. Here is the source of the function:

```
unsigned char* getByteImFromImageData(double *image, int start, int size, bool useManContrast){
unsigned char* newim;
newim = (unsigned char*)malloc(size*sizeof(unsigned char));
double mini = +INFINITY;
double maxi = 0;
if (!useManContrast){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (*(image + start + i) > maxi) maxi = *(image + start + i);
        if (*(image + start + i) < mini) mini = *(image + start + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *(newim + i) = (*(image + start + i) - mini) / (maxi - mini) * 255.0;
    }
}
else {
    mini = contrastMin;
    maxi = contrastMax;
    double temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        temp = (*(image + start + i) - mini) / (maxi - mini) * 255.0;
        if (temp>255) temp = 255;
        if (temp < 0) temp = 0;
        *(newim + i) = (unsigned char) temp;
    }
}

return(newim);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a different overload of Bitmap constructor and see if you experience this problem again?

Comment: Are all the images of the same type?

Comment: How would you use another overload of the Bitmap constructor? The images are all of the same type. RGB bitmap with values between 0 and 255. @DeniseSkidmore

Comment: Other Bitmap constructors:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you using the image in more than one place?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.110).aspx  "If you want to use the same image in multiple PictureBox controls, create a clone of the image for each PictureBox. Accessing the same image from multiple controls causes an exception to occur."

Comment: Is the problem the size or the aspect ratio?  The non-working example is the opposite orientation of the working examples.  Try: 550*600 (smaller than all working images, but opposite orientation) and 650*630 (same orientation as working images, but larger.)

Comment: It seems like the size is the problem. `200*300` pixels works perfectly fine. So does `100*100`. But `99*99` causes the crash `Parameter is not valid.`@DeniseSkidmore

Comment: I would be very very grateful if someone could help me out here. This problem is driving me crazy :-/
@DeniseSkidmore ?

Comment: You may have found an entirely different problem than the one I told you to look for.  I was very specific about the suggested tests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680618/exception-parameter-is-not-valid-on-passing-new-image-to-picturebox

Comment: I looks like this is not an uncommon issue.  I suggest you search https://www.google.com/webhp?q=picturebox+image+Parameter+is+not+valid and edit your answer with things you have tried that didn't work for you, or if you do find something that works post your own answer.